# Two sets A, B of size n. Each element selects one element of the other set. Probability of no mutual selection?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Came up in a challenge list of probability interview Q's.

You have two sets A, B of size n each. Each member in set A designates a member in B at random. Each member in set B designates a member in A at random. What is the probability of no mutual designation?

Where I got to:
Use an n-tuple (k_1, k_2, ...k_n) to represent how many members of A are designated to the i-th member of B.

I get that each tuple is created by (n!)/[(k_1!)(k_2!)...(k_n!)] designations of A. Or more simply ${n \choose k_1 ... k_n}$

For each n-tuple, I also get there are $\Pi_k (n-k_i)^{k_i}$ to satisfy the no mutual requirement from B's designations.

Putting that altogether I get:

$\Sigma_{k_1 + k_2 .... k_n = n}  {n \choose k_1 ... k_n} * \Pi_k (n-k_i)^{k_i}$

Which seems to be really close to multinomial expansion, but not quite.

Tried a few other methods, too. But they keep running into the issue that each tuple allocation (barring permuting the order) results in different number of combinations (ways to reach via A times ways to preserve no mutual from B).

Comment: In an interview question, it's possible the desired answer is "well, it tends to $\frac1e$ as $n \to \infty$" rather than an exact value.

Comment: That's a fair point. But it's not immediately obvious to me why $\frac{1}{e}$ is the limit case. Was there a more simple way to think of the problem?

Comment: Try inclusion-exclusion on the events $E_i$ that element $i$ of $A$ is mapped to an element of $B$ that is mapped to $i$.

Comment: @OttR-A.Yu: The two selections taken together define a permutation of $A$; there is no mutual selection if and only if this permutation is a [derangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement). The number of derangements is the integer closest to $\frac{n!}e$, so the probability is very close to $\frac1e$.

Comment: Is that still the case if both designations can be many-to-one?

Comment: In the many-to-one case (which is what I assumed) we are no longer looking at derangements, but we still expect a probability of $\frac1e$ for all the same general reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I encounter problems like these, my instinct is always to:

1. Use the [method of moments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_moments_(probability_theory)) to prove that the number of mutual selections (or whatever) converges to a Poisson random variable in distribution;
2. Conclude that as $n \to \infty$, the probability of having no mutual selections goes to $e^{-\mu}$, where $\mu$ is the expected number of mutual selections (here, $1$).

If $\mathbf X$ is the number of mutual selections, we can show that for a constant $k$ and $n \ge k$, $\mathbb E[\binom{\mathbf X}{k}] = k! \binom nk^2 n^{-2k} \sim \frac1{k!}$, which is what we expect from a Poisson random variable with mean $1$. So that ticks off the first box.

(Why this expected value? Well, $\binom{\mathbf X}{k}$ counts the number of $k$-sets of mutual selections. There are $k! \binom nk^2$ ways to describe a potential such $k$-set in terms of which $A$-elements are matched with which $B$-elements, and each one is actually a $k$-set of mutual selections with probability $n^{-2k}$.)

In particular, $\mathbb E[X] = 1$, so $\Pr[\mathbf X = 0] \to e^{-1}$ as $n \to \infty$.